# Troubles removing ignore tags from Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, troubleshooting

This may be a stupid question on my part and/or possibly a duplicate, but I'm having problems deleting ignored tags from Stack Overflow.

When I hover over them, I don't see any "X" to delete the tag nor does the description box popup like it used to. Also, the ignored tags are not ignoring any questions anymore.

If it helps, I have nearly 200 to 300 ignore tags selected [atm](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/atm#Abbreviation).

Comment: What browser and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 4.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me.

Did you deactivate JavaScript?

Try to clear your cache and cookies eventually to begin with a fresh state.
Try also another browser to check if it is really a global problem or just on one browser.

Comment: I can still use js, but I'll try your other solutions.

Comment: So, I tried clearing the cache and it failed. When I tried using chrome it succeeded. Looks like FF is the culprit. Not exactly sure why though... did they do an update recently or something? At any rate, thanks :)

Comment: Firefox 4.0.1 is working well for me. Maybe you have an extension responsible for this? Try safe-mode eventually. Check for update.

Comment: I deleted a couple of tags in Chrome and now it's working well in FF. I'm not sure what the exact cause was, but I'm pretty sure that the amount of tags had something to do with it.

Comment: Also, I'm using FF 4.0.1